# Is it safer to remove a battery from an ebike before charging it?

Tags: battery

It is possible for me to remove the battery of my ebike and I am wondering if it is safer to do that before charging it. Could there be a potential damage to the electric motor while charging a battery that is left on the bike?

Comment: Frame question - would you take a phone battery out of the phone before charging?

Comment: @Criggie: There are people who charge their RC car (or airplane) batteries in a bucket of sand. General Motors recommends you don’t charge their Chevy Bolt indoors. So there are cases of people taking the batteries elsewhere to charge ;)

Answer (score 3):

If the electronics are designed and implemented correctly I see no way for charging to damage *anything*.

That being said, there have been rare cases where batteries went up in flames while charging. *If* it goes up in flames it’s obviously better for the bike if it happens away from it ;)

Charging makes the battery heat up. This reduces life time and (above a certain point) increases risk of fire. Depending on how the battery is mounted it might stay cooler when charged away from the bike.

Comment: I'd say with a flaming battery one of your least concerns is what happens to the bike.

Answer (score 1):

The general recommendation is to charge away from the flammable things. If the whole bicycle can be brought away, should be good enough to charge on a bicycle, unless it is expensive enough you also want to protect it.

If you just own a flat, not a house, it may be very difficult to find a charging place "away from any flammable items". In this case the battery ideally should be charged in a [protection box](https://www.derschweighofer.ch/MODSTER-BAT-Safe-Lipo-Tresor-XL-a267084) (not affiliated). Such boxes are available on the market. Of course, you need to remove the battery to put it into the box.